# What all data fields we can capture from "user_about_me" in graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What all data fields can be captured from user_about_me in graph API? Fields like work, education are included in `user_about_me` or we have to use `user_education_history` for that data?

Comment: [_“Provides access to a person's personal description (the 'About Me' section on their Profile) through the bio property on the User object.”_](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_about_me)